# read.table to read multiple files from the directory in R

Tags: r, import, filenames, dir, read.table

My purpose is to read multiple files from a directory into a giant table. But running the code reports

> error: "invalid description argument'.

Anyone has idea why this happens? I checked my files, they are all in the same format.

```
dir<- "D:\\Concentration" #work dir
filename<- list.files(dir)
### Read in data file
Data<-read.table(paste(dir,filename,sep="/"),sep=",")
```

Comment: use `setwd(dir)` to set your working directory. then read the files one by one and combine using cbind/rbind/merge/...

Comment: In addition to @mts's comment, for reading multiple files, try`do.call(rbind, lapply(filename, read.table, sep=","))`

Comment: It usually better to use `file.path` instead of `paste` to construct paths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `full.names=T` in the `list.files` so you dont need to set directory.  That way you code is more portable.  From the comments @akrun

```
fnames <- list.files(dir, full.names = T)
do.call(rbind, lapply(fnames, read.table, sep=","))
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a list of lists rather than `rbind` them?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a `tidyverse` answer:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- list.files() %>%
  map(read.table) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```